# Match identifiers that aren't already quoted

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a JavaScript helper function that quotes PostgreSQL identifiers that are not yet quoted, e.g.

`("alreadyQuoted".not_quoted).camelCase`

should become

`("alreadyQuoted"."not_quoted")."camelCase"`

For that I want to write a regular expression that finds all identifiers not yet quoted but I can't get it to ignore the quoted identifiers.

I have this so far

```js
console.log('("alreadyQuoted".not_quoted).camelCase'.replace(/\b[a-z0-9_]+\b/gi, m => `"${m}"`))
```

Comment: can you have unbalanced quoted identifiers in strings ?

Comment: You can try [`\b(?!")([a-z0-9_]+)(?!")\b`](https://regex101.com/r/4E2TZF/1/)

Comment: Quotes should be balanced. Your suggestion worked perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your string doesn't have unbalanced `"` you can use this

```
\b(?!")([a-z0-9_]+)(?!")\b
```

[image]

```js
let str = '("alreadyQuoted".not_quoted).camelCase'
let final = str.replace(/\b(?!")([a-z0-9_]+)(?!")\b/gi,  m => `"${m}"`)

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! What tool did you use to visualize the regex?

Comment: @kraf this is called regex visualizer, [`jex.im`](https://jex.im/regulex/)